# try to export getting export.php error as follows

Tags: php, database

I trying to export db but getting the error

[image: error getting from export]

```
export.php: Missing parameter: what[a@doc/html/faq.ht!ml#faqmissingparameters@documentation]

export.php: Missing parameter: export_type[a@doc/html/faq.html#faqmissingparameters@documentation]
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `Adminer` instead of `PhpMyAdmin` and check if it helps!

> https://www.adminer.org/

Also, you can export the database using the command with SSH:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME > DATABASE_FILENAME.sql
```

More, using the below command you can backup database through Magento CLI:

```
php bin/magento setup:backup --db
```

Please visit the official Magento document for Back up database and more using CLI. > https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: after putting these command where can i find these files?

Comment: If this command you run magento root. you can find the magento root @Iehab

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If you run php bin/magento setup:backup --db than on success you will be able to see the path in the console message: like DB backup path: /var/www/html/magento2/var/backups/1434133011_db.sql. Accept the answer if it helps so it will not remain open. Thanks.